# MOVZX x86 encoding

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

Looking at some disassembly, I see the following line:

```
0f b7 8c 00 c4 99 86     movzx ecx,WORD PTR [eax+eax*1-0x3e79663c]
```

How is the disassembler is getting the value "0x3e79663c" from that encoding? It does not appear to be relative to the address of the instruction.

Looking at the raw bytes, if we subtract 0x8699c4 from 0, we get 0xff79663c. The last 3 bytes of that number are what the disassembler has, but I still don't see where the most significant byte (0x3e) comes from.

---

**Update**

It turns out objdump is printing out in a strange way. It prints the missing byte as the next opcode for some reason.

```
  35:   83 c7 01                add    edi,0x1
  38:   0f b7 8c 00 c4 99 86    movzx  ecx,WORD PTR [eax+eax*1-0x3e79663c]
  3f:   c1 
  40:   8d 81 30 96 86 c1       lea    eax,[ecx-0x3e7969d0]
```

Thanks to Jester for figuring this out.

Comment: It's not the next opcode, it's just a continuation line. You can set up a wider display if you want, using `--insn-width=15`.

Comment: `objdump -drwC -Mintel` disables line-wrapping (`-w`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a byte from the end of the instruction.
It should be `0f b7 8c 00 c4 99 86 c1` from which the offset is `0xc18699c4` which is `-0x3e79663c`.